# Сколько памяти занимают объекты?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Провел несколько тестов, и был весьма удивлен... Режим компиляции x64. Первый тест показал 4 байта, здесь все нормально. Второй 32. Ого подумал я. И трейтий 32 WTF ???

```
static int count = 10000000;

static void Array_C()
{
    var size = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
    var arr = new int[count];

    for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = i;
    }

    var mem = GC.GetTotalMemory(true) - size;

    Console.WriteLine("Выделено памяти: " + mem + ", размер одного объекта: " + Math.Truncate((double)mem / count) + ", код последней " + arr.Last());
}

static void Array_E()
{
    var size = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
    var arr = new object[count];

    for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = new object();
    }

    var mem = GC.GetTotalMemory(true) - size;

    Console.WriteLine("Выделено памяти: " + mem + ", размер одного объекта: " + Math.Truncate((double)mem / count) + ", код последней " + arr.Last().GetHashCode());
}

static void Array_F()
{
    var size = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
    var arr = new C[count];

    for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = new C { Val0 = i, Val1 = i };
    }

    var mem = GC.GetTotalMemory(false) - size;

    Console.WriteLine("Выделено памяти: " + mem + ", размер одного объекта: " + Math.Truncate((double)mem / count) + ", код последней " + arr.Last().Val0 + arr.Last().Val1);
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
class C
{
    public int Val0;
    public int Val1;
}
```

Вопрос даже не в том почему во втором тесте один экземляр занимает 32 байта. А в том почему в третьем тесте экземпляр не занимает 40 байт.

Comment: Ну так вы просто не правильно измеряете (как правильно и вообще возможно ли правильно измерить я не знаю)

Comment: А почему именно 40?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Почему не правильно? Первый тест показывает, что все правильно. int занимает 4 байта.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight потому что 32 + 4 + 4. Если object занимает 32, тогда объект с двумя переменными по 4, должен занимать 40

Comment: @МаксБурцев, а у меня показывает 5 байт

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0U6U5.png

Comment: @АндрейNOP поставьте count 100000000

Comment: В обычном .NET минимальный размер объекта - 24 байта, размер служебного блока - 16 байт, не знаю как в .NET core. А методика расчета неправильная, да. Первый вызов etTotalMemory должен быть после создания массива, а не до.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight обоснуйте не правильность. Первый вызов замеряет до выделения второй после. Кроме того опыт c int показывает правильность.

Comment: @МаксБурцев второй и третий неправильны (первый нормально). Результат искажается из-за дополнительной памяти под массив ссылок. Впрочем это не так уж важно. Видимо под .NET Core минимальный размер объекта - 32 байта, что и показал ваш код.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight 32 - 8 (на ссылку) = 24

Comment: @PetSerAl да, затупил...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Во первых, в данном коде неправильно измеряется размер для массива ссылочных типов. Код:

```
var size = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
var arr = new object[count];

for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
        arr[i] = new object();
}

var mem = GC.GetTotalMemory(true) - size;
```

Измеряет память под массив ссылок + память под объекты. Надо так:

```
var arr = new object[count];
var size = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
        arr[i] = new object();
}

var mem = GC.GetTotalMemory(true) - size;
```

Во вторых, арифметика `Размер C = Размер object + 2 * Размер int` не работает: все несколько сложнее.

1. В CLR существует минимальный размер объекта, см. [object.h](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/object.h)

   ```
    //
    // The generational GC requires that every object be at least 12 bytes
    // in size.   

    #define MIN_OBJECT_SIZE     (2*sizeof(BYTE*) + sizeof(ObjHeader))
   ```

Для 64-разрядной версии минимальный размер 2 * 8 + 8 = 24. Размер типа, меньшего 24 байта, дополняется до 24.

(Определение ObjHeader здесь: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/gc/env/gcenv.object.h)

2. Размер служебного блока, добавляемого к любому ссылочному типу, равен 16 байт (для x86 - 8 байт, см. например [здесь](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20481/NET-Type-Internals-From-a-Microsoft-CLR-Perspecti#4), для x64 в два раза больше).
3. Кроме того, предположительно, работает дополнение размера до числа, кратного 8.

Таким образом:

> Размер объекта с 1 int полем = 24 байта
> Размер объекта с 2 int полями = 24 байта
> Размер объекта с 3 int полями = 32 байта

Comment: Мне как раз и нужно посчитать не только размер объекта но и ссылку на него. Т.к. Для построения деревьев стоит выбор использовать объекты и ссылки, или массивы и указатели.

Comment: Получается так что используя указатели и ручное управление памятью я могу экономить более чем в 2 раза.

Comment: @МаксБурцев начните лучше с массивов структур, а не с указателей

Comment: @МаксБурцев Да, с помощью указателей и unsafe-кода можно получить выигрыш в производительности при обработке больших массивов. См. например здесь: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/8d5880fe-108e-47d2-bbd7-4669e0aec1ec/-2-?forum=programminglanguageru