# Где сохранится значение свойства экземпляра класса в C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

Имеем такой класс:

```cs
class Foo {
  public int Property => 123;
}
```

Как видим, свойство имеет только `getter` и всегда возвращает константное значение - литерал `123`.

Если создать 2 и более экземпляров, продублируется ли значение `132`, или `Property` будет указывать на одну область памяти?

Какой из вариантов окажется менее затратным `Foo` или `Bar`?

```cs
class Bar {
  private static readonly int _ConstValue = 123;
  public int Property => _ConstValue;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131891/discussion-on-question-by-alexander-lonberg-----).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос достаточно простой.

Начну с того, что если изменить второй пример вот так:

```cs
class Bar
{
    private const int _ConstValue = 123;
    public int Property => _ConstValue;
}
```

То оба класса будут оптимизированы на выходе в идентичный набор инструкций процессора.

Как известно, свойство - это группа методов `get` и `set` и в данном случае метод `get_Property` при использовании константы будет скомпилирован вот так.

```
mov eax, 0x7b
ret
```

Записать в регистр EAX константу `0x7b`, что означает число 123 и вернуть из метода.

Весь вопрос сводится здесь к тому, чем будет отличаться `static readonly` поле и константа, и так как статическое поле инициализируется всего один раз за время выполнения приложения, то что там происходит при инициализации - с точки зрения производительности совершенно всё равно.

А вот как изменится сам метод `get_Property` - он просто начнет работать с памятью.

```
mov eax, [ecx+4]
ret
```

Записать в регистр EAX значение из ячейки памяти по адресу из регистра ECX со смещением 4 байта.

Код метода конечно будет изменяться в зависимости от условий вызова и доступных компилятору оптимизаций, но смысл останется тот же.

Как итог: что быстрее, записать ячейку памяти в регистр процессора или константу? Определенно константу, так как при этом процессору просто не нужно обращаться к памяти, значение константы уже у него будет в кеше в выполняемом коде.

Но стоит учесть, что обе инструкции работают молниеносно быстро, и разницу можно будет ощутить только с специфических случаях. Другими словами, про константы вместо статичных `readonly` полей не стоит забывать и по возможности использовать.

*Если интересно, есть ли разница между литералом и константой - в скомпилированном коде её нет. Это совершенно одно и то же. Разница есть только на уровне C#.*

Comment: Изначально я интересовался скоростью доступа к константным/static значениям через this. Но так сошлись звезды, что тестил разные варианты всего с 2-мя int, не зная о минимальном размере объекта. И что я должен был подумать, увидев что пустой объект(2 геттера), занимает столько же памяти сколько и с 2-мя полями(в вопросе такого нет) - 24байта. Конечно я решил что литерал записался в некое поле и занимает память в каждом инстансе, да еще и "зрительный_обман". Т.е. вопрос был буквально: куда попадет такой константный getter. Уже нашел - пустой инстанс будет минимум 24б и таким же как с 2-мя int.

Comment: Парадокс в том, что этот ответ привел к изначальному(незаданному) вопросу - оптимальные варианты константных/статичных свойств через this. Об использовании констант я даже и не думал.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, мне кажется уже был вопрос, что из себя объекты в памяти представляют, все вот эти заголовки поля и т.д. и откуда эти 24 байта берутся

Comment: @Grundy Предыстория и простая арифметика: объект с 2-мя-int-гетеррами должен занимать меньше памяти чем объект с 2-мя-гетеррами+2-поля. Арифметика не сработала и занимаемая память таких объектов одинакова. Я решил что компилятор воспринял это так: _Раз в геттере нет переменных, значит не сохраняем функцию, вычисляем и сохраняем значение в памяти._ - тут вроде все логично. А дальше тупик: _Если объекты равны, значит это вычисленное/сохраненное значение копируется в каждый инстанс и мы получаем таких же 2 поля_ - но ведь это похоже на глупость. next1->

Comment: @Grundy <-prev1. Я ведь не зря явно указал в вопросе, что меня интересует не `getter`, а буквально `getter+литерал`, т.е. значение которое может быть вычислено до первого создания объекта и где-то сохранено(как static). И как такое значение будет использовано - дублируется ли оно для каждого инстанса или возвращается из одного адреса. Вопросов по таким заранее вычисленным геттерам я не нашел. next2->

Comment: @Grundy <-prev2. Ответ меня убедил, что константа и литерал будут возвращены из одного адреса. А почему возник такой вопрос и подвох с неверной арифметикой раскрылся в 2-х int-ах и [был найден здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/779212/305162). И как о таком можно догадаться, ничего не зная о 24 байтах.